# Cannot use async validator with http.get call

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous

I keep having the error:

```
**ERROR Error: NG01101: Expected async validator to return Promise or Observable. 
Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01101**
```

This error URL does not exist.
The error occurs in the call of the validator.

This is my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {EmailValidator} from email.validator';
    
export class AppComponent{
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form =  fb.group({
          email: ['bla@alem.pt', {asyncValidators:[EmailValidator(this.apiService)],updateOn: 'blur'}] //UPDATED with the help of Volodymyr Herchuk
      });
    }
}
```

**email.validator.ts**

```
import {AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';
import {ApiService} from '../services/api.service';
import {map} from 'rxjs';

export function EmailValidator(apiService:ApiService):AsyncValidatorFn{
    return (control: AbstractControl)=>{
        return apiService.validateEmail(control.value) 
            .pipe(
                    map(response=>{
                        return response.valid?response.valid:null;
                    })
            );
    };
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    //returns {valid:true} or {valid:false}
    public validateEmail(email: string){ // Observable
        return this.http.get('/api/:email'.replace(':email', email)
        );
    }
}
```

I have been reading a lot examples, specially this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wX6iVLyy4M0), which is a similar case, but i cannot find a solution.
Can anyone tell me what i am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `EmailValidator()` so it will return validator function instead of just `EmailValidator`

---

I wanted to add it as a comment but I can't((

Comment: Thank you! That was the correct plus adding the parameter this.apiService.